# Pandas doesn't recognize columns in a document

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read multiple tab delimited files (.tab) using pandas, and all files contain 250 rows and varying number of columns (more than 1). Some of the resulting data frames have expected number of rows and columns. However, in some of them all columns are recognized as a single column. Those data frames have expected number of rows, but only one column. I checked if the problematic documents have any unexpected line breaks or separators (or absence of thereof) and I wasn't able to find anything different from the 'good' documents. Does anyone have any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: are you sure there was no other separator? if not maybe the files are corrupted and you'll need to parse them with regex can you post the raw text of one of the files in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was an extra line on the top of some documents I was trying to open. After checking all data frames and using a skiprow argument while reading files, everything worked fine.